# Connection refused {:class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I want to use the ELK stack for applications on rails. Logstash standard configuration:

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And when I execute the command in the terminal (`cat development.log | nice bin/logstash -f logstash.conf`), then the following error occurs:

```
 Connection refused {:class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}
 Connection refused {:class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}
 Settings: Default pipeline workers: 2
 Connection refused {:class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}
 Connection refused {:class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}
 Logstash startup completed
 Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at '["http://localhost:9200/"]', but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down! {:client_config=>{:hosts=>["http://localhost:9200/"], :ssl=>nil, :transport_options=>{:socket_timeout=>0, :request_timeout=>0, :proxy=>nil, :ssl=>{}}, :transport_class=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::Manticore, :logger=>nil, :tracer=>nil, :reload_connections=>false, :retry_on_failure=>false, :reload_on_failure=>false, :randomize_hosts=>false}, :error_message=>"В соединении отказано (Connection refused)", :class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Connection refused is an indication that Logstash can't connect to Elasticsearch.

There are three possible reasons:

1. You aren't running Elasticsearch on the same host as logstash (you've configured it to go to localhost:9200 which means you are expecting it to be running on the same machine).
2. You've configured Elasticsearch to bind to a specific IP address on the local machine instead of all addresses (change elasticsearch.yml to have `network.host=0.0.0.0` to bind to all addresses)
3. You're running on a server with SELinux in enforcing mode, but it's not configured to allow connections between logstash and elasticsearch.

Basic diagnostics should tell you what's the case.  `netstat -an | grep 9200` to see if Elasticsearch is running and bound to a specific address.  `getenforce` to see if SELinux is enabled.